# Is there a bug in PowerShell 4 (and less) using call operator with double quoted arguments?

Tags: powershell, call, powershell-4.0, double-quotes

I noticed a difference between PowerShell 4 and PowerShell 5.

Lets consider the following PowerShell script:

```
. SomeProgram.exe "something=""Hello World!"""
```

> Arguments seen by 'SomeProgram.exe' with **PowerShell 4 (and maybe
>   less)**:
>
> - arg 0: something=Hello
> - arg 1: World!
>
> Arguments seen by 'SomeProgram.exe' with **PowerShell 5**:
>
> - arg 0: something=Hello World!

*Please note that this difference only occurs when the argument contains some text before the double quote:*

- *"sometext""Hello World!"""  KO*

*but*

- *"""Hello World!"""  OK*

**Conclusion:**

PowerShell 4 seems to have a bug when it comes to parsing an argument in form of:

```
ATextWithoutSpace"A Text with space"
```

PowerShell 5 strips double quotes and considers the whole string as a single argument (like it should be).

PowerShell 4 strips double quotes but makes several arguments by splitting the string with spaces.

Is there a way to get the same behavior between PowerShell 4 et PowerShell 4?

Comment: If you are in PowerShell, just single quote your argument string --> `. SomeProgram.exe 'something="Hello World!"'`.

Comment: If the argument is a constant and not some interesting expression, you can use `--%` (stop parsing) to pass arguments to external commands as-is, e.g. `--% something="Hello World"`. In this case there is no need for quoting at all. Note that it's then still up to the invoked program to actually parse its command line.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, this doesn't explain why there is such a difference... It would be nice if someone could confirm that there is a bug in older PowerShell versions.